# Need help with the sum of the binomial coefficients: ${k+l \choose l}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am tring to prove the following equality :

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n {k+l \choose l} = {n+l+1 \choose l+1} $

However, I did not manage to find a proof... Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Induction on $n$.

Comment: It works ! Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome. You might want to post your solution as an answer and even, possibly, to accept it after a while.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by induction on $n$ :

Basis : For $n=0$, we have ${l \choose l}={0+l+1 \choose l+1} = 1$

Inductive step : Let's assume that, for some nonnegative $n$ : $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n {k+l \choose l} = {n+l+1 \choose l+1} $

Then : $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {k+l \choose l} = {n+l+1 \choose l+1} + {n+l+1 \choose l}= {n+l+2 \choose l+1}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\binom {r+a}a=\binom {r+a+1}
{a+1}- \binom {r+a}{a+1}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n {k+l \choose l} &= \sum_{k=0}^n {k+l+1\choose l+1}-{k+l\choose l+1}\\
&={n+l+1 \choose l+1}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$
via telescoping, as ${l\choose l+1}=0$.